# Apache Spark ALS algorithm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to run a movie recommendation app based on ALS algorithm on Apache Spark using Python
I’m using Spark2.2.0-Hadoop2.7 
I have one master and 2 workers
When I want to run the app using this command

```
Spark-submit  —master Spark://192.168.190.132:7077 —total-executor-cores 8 —executor-memory 2g engine.py
```

I get errors it says the ratings.csv file doesn’t exist( I checked the addres everything is correct)

> error picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgK2Q.jpg

But when I use this command 
`Spark-submit app.py`it works but fails after a while

I’m not using HDFS I load dataset locally 
Do I need to copy datasets to all worker nodes?

Comment: When you aren't using a single point of contact like hdfs, you need to have the files avaiable on all worker nodes.

Comment: @cronoik so I should copy datasets to all worker nodes or use HDFS ? If using HDFS I just need to give the HDFS address?

Comment: I recommend using the HDFS as it offers you a wide range of possibilities.

Comment: I copied datasets to all worker nodes exactly the same location but it doesn’t read the ratings and it doesn’t show any errors, I will use HDFS

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload dataset to HDFS if you want to work as spark standalone spark.using webui for all worker nodes.using hdfs -put to upload on HDFS.